# How to address the issue of the widespread use of protected material in informal publications?

Tags: copyright

One thing that always bothered me is the liberal use of protected material in informal academic publications (for example Powerpoint presentations, handouts and internal reports rather than published papers).

It seems that the "everything on the Internet is free" attitude is also widespread in the academic world. And while I regularly spend a considerable amount of time either creating the graphic material I need or search for it on the Internet, nearly everybody else is not even thinking about it. Need a nice picture of a sunset or a little fish to include in your graphic? Just google and use the first one, without thinking twice!

This does not happen on single occasions only, I've made that experience in several countries, working in different environments.

Sometimes, among co-workers and friends I raise this issue and am usually met with understanding. Most of them see the problem with the additional time they need to spend to search for relevant material or the creation of an appropriate space to include copyright notes or references to graphic material. Some also mention that it would be considered unprofessional including a user name on the Internet as the source for their imagery.

My questions therefore is, how do I sensibly raise this issue among supervisors (which may consider this a waste of time) or an unknown crowd, especially considering above-mentioned criteria?

Comment: To quote section 107 of the US Copyright act: "[t]he fair use of a copyrighted work, including such use by reproduction in copies or phonorecords or by any other means specified by that section, for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, **teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research,** is not an infringement of copyright."  So at least in the US, it looks like you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: As JeffE points out, what you're describing is protected fair use in the US, and indeed, in many if not most Berne convention signatories, so it's not clear *why* this bothers you or what "the issue" actually is.  As such, I'm not sure the question is answerable.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @JeffE, it being legal in the US due to Fair Use doesn't prevent someone from suing you. That could be quite costly to defend, and it's not guaranteed to get thrown out automatically. You, or your expensive lawyer, actually need to make an argument against the copyright holder's team of lawyers in briefs or maybe actually in person to a judge in a courtroom. Those costs can add up. The odds of suit from a presentation with a stolen pic are low, IMO, but they are not zero.

Comment: _...doesn't prevent someone from suing you_ — Okay, sure.  But why is that _your_ problem?

Comment: @BillBarth the odds of being struck by lightning while walking down the street on a cloudy day are also low but not zero. It seems like a strange principle by which to live your life that we should be afraid of doing things even when we are confident that they are ethical and legal just because of some hypothetical fear of a lawsuit by some malevolent person. Is a copyright lawsuit for using an image from Google Images in a presentation really the biggest thing you have to worry about in your life? If so, I envy you.

Comment: @JeffE, it's not Bill Barth's problem, but it might be OP's or anyone else in OP's position. If you use copyright protected material without license, you may be subject to an expensive lawsuit, DMCA takedown request, or have to deal with a cease and desist letter. All of which is annoying, two of which may remove your material from world view, and one of which is, perhaps, ignored at your peril. It's one thing to tell others that it's normal to be cavalier about these risks, and it's entirely another to be cavalier yourself. Personally, I never want to have to defend a copyright lawsuit.

Comment: @DanRomik, same to you as to JeffE, but also, there's a difference between malevolence and corporate policy. Several of the big publishers are on lookout for misuse of their IP. They might choose to deal with you (a malevolent misuser of their property in their opinion) in a way that is perfectly legal, moral, and right from their perspective. Telling OP to not worry about the chance of lawsuit , DMCA take down, or C&D is pretty cavalier in my opinion. People lose Fair Use defenses all the time, though I don't know of an academic/research case where they have. It all still costs money.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I thought I made clear why I voted to close (I didn't downvote, incidentally): the question "this thing bothers me...how do I raise this issue?" is unanswerable unless OP feels like telling us why this bothers them and what purpose they have in raising the issue.  Without that, it invites answers - like yours - discussing whether or not this should bother OP, rather than answers to the stated question.

Answer (score 3):

From an ethical point of view, I think most people can still sleep well despite taking the first fish from Google from time to time.

From a legal perspective, it depends on your jurisdiction and the license of the image. As Jeff points out, it's often fine in many places.

You should define your goals (ethics vs. legal), and act accordingly (which is my case would be do nothing).